# Transferring variable to C++ from python and running C++ at full speed (not python speed)

Tags: python, c++

I am doing some operations in a Python code that are too slow for python.

I need to explain a little the global context of what I am doing.

I am reading some input from a board in python. It is a continous operation (*I read continuously the datas from the board*).

I need to treat those datas in continous also by doing some computations on those. They are saved in numpys arrays in practice.

To increase the speed of thoose computation I would like to run them in C or C++.

But as everything is continous, I need a very fast transfer of thoose numpy arrays from python to C++. Thus my question are the following :

What is the better way to run a C++ code from python such that the variable transfer from numpy arrays to C++ tables is the fastest possible ? Is it possible in the ideal case that the C++ code "**directly**" read the numpy arrays in the memory ?

I have read some topic about using C++ in Python but I am not sure if the C++ will be run at full speed or if it is just to simply use a C++ code in python (*but it will run slower than a fully C++ program*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to achieve can be done by using a precompiled library via cython.

Compile your C/C++ code into a dynamic library (.so on *nix, .dll on Windows); `export` the functions you want to use from python.

You can then load the library in your python code using `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) and pass a pointer to your numpy array using `numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html).

If you make sure that the numpy array is continuous, it can be used in C/C++ like expected.